# How to add an external library to a Qt project in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator

Qt Creator **my_project -> Right Click -> Add Library** no longer works. It was working before, with an earlier Qt version (5.8.0), and I had even added a few libraries, but for some reason it just doesn't show the **Add Library** window anymore. It's like that tab *(Add Library)* is deactivated/ inactive.

What could be the  issue?

Thank you all in advance.

> Qt Creator 4.3.1
>   Based on Qt 5.9.0 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)
>   Built on May 28 2017 14:10:10
>   From revision bfd818b2b1
>   Copyright 2008-2017 The Qt Company Ltd. All rights reserved.
>   The program is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: What is your version of Qt Creator ? and did you build it from the source ? As a workaround, i guess you can still add your external library by editing directly the .pro file of your project.

Comment: Qt Creator 4.3.1 I did build it from the source. And it's not just one project, it's all projects, including any new ones I create @Scab

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression bug from QtCreator 4.3.  There has been a bug report filed here:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18263